# How to run a shell script inside a shell script

Tags: bash

I am using bash on Mac OSX.

I have a shell file named `myshell.sh` and I use it to do a lot of things.

I have a entrance.sh file which contains:

```
# content of entrance.sh
./myshell.sh arg1 arg2
./myshell.sh arg3 arg4
```

But when I run `entrance.sh` I got a error:

```
./entrance.sh: line 2: myshell.sh: command not found
```

I can run the myshell.sh directly.

What can I do?

Comment: Use full paths instead of relative.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to use the full paths to achieve this?

Comment: Is `entrance.sh` in the same directory as `myshell.sh` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes it's the same. After switching to full paths instead of relative, it works. thanks to YoMismo

Comment: Isn't there on OSX a folder equivalent to `/usr/local/[s]bin` where you could put all your scripts ?

Comment: @Nasha I am using scripts in a very casual way. I put them in the directory where I need to execute the script.

Comment: The advantage of putting them in a directory that is included in the PATH variable is to spare the hassle of the full path for running a script, even casually. It also makes the script independent of its location and increases portability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`./myshell.sh` means the script `myshell.sh` is found in the *current* directory. If you run this script from somewhere else, it won't work. You *could* use full paths, but in this case, the only sensible solutions are:

1. Adding the location of `myshell.sh` to your `$PATH` (in case, `myshell.sh` really is something that is supposed to be called from everywhere). So, add `PATH="$PATH":/dir/of/myshell` at the beginning of the outer script.
2. Put `myshell.sh` somewhere so that it's accessible from everywhere (just like all other executables on the system). That would be `/usr/local/bin` most likely. Use this only if this script is universally useful.

If the scripts rely on local files in their directory (and may even break down and do damage if called from elsewhere), then you should either leave it in the current form (this actually prevents you to call them from places you are not supposed to), or use `cd` inside the script to get to the proper location. Be careful, use absolute paths in shell scripts for `cd`, it is too easy to break stuff if something goes wrong and you go out `..` and `cd`-ing further in fails, you could escape out of your directory and reign chaos all over the parent directories.

Mostly I'd recommend solution #1.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by YoMismo you should use full path in your script or `cd` to your scripts directory.

```
# content of entrance.sh
/full/path/myshell.sh arg1 arg2
/full/path2/myshell.sh arg3 arg4
```

Or (but this is a very ugly solution)

```
# content of entrance.sh
cd /full/path
./myshell.sh arg1 arg2
cd /full/path2
./myshell.sh arg3 arg4
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that ./myshell.sh does not have execute permissions (need to perform 'chmod +x myshell.sh'), or is not in the current directory (need to move it to the same directory as entrance.sh).

Try calling ./myshell from the same directory as ./entrance.sh, do you get the same result?

Also, if you want to be more certain that you run your script you can call bash directly on it:

```
/bin/bash ./myshell arg1 arg2
```