# Not able to run a nohup script inside a ksh

Tags: ksh, nohup

I'm trying to read a text file (containing set of instructions)

```
#!/bin/ksh
INPUT=input.txt
OLDIFS=$IFS
while IFS='~' read -r ACTIVE process_name PATH  STOP START DB
do
    
    if [ $ACTIVE == 'Y' ]; then
    echo "IS ACTIVE?  : $ACTIVE "
    echo "PROCESS NAME : $process_name"
    echo "PATH1 : $PATH"
    echo "STOP_SCRIPT : $STOP"
    echo "START_SCRIPT : $START"
    echo "DB_QUERY : $DB"
    echo "*****************************************************"
    echo "starting $process_name"
    cd $PATH
    $START
    fi
    done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

A sample instruction in input.txt is as below

```
Y~ABC~/path/to/dir/work/~kill~nohup ABC.ksh  >nohup.out 2>&1 &~~
```

the above script reads the stop script as

```
nohup ABC.ksh >nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

but when I run ./test.ksh

the prompt doesnt return and is stuck at

```
/path2/to/dir/> Sending nohup output to nohup.out.

/path2/to/dir/>
```

If I hardcode "nohup ABC.ksh  >nohup.out 2>&1 &"
in the script, it runs fine

I have tried
nohup ABC.ksh  >nohup.out 2>&1 &
nohup ABC.ksh &

But it doesnt work
Since ABC.KSH runs in while infinite loop I can not wait for control to return

Please help!!!

Already tried
[How to run a shell script inside a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183998/how-to-run-a-shell-script-inside-a-shell-script)
And other available solutions, still not working

Comment: My guess is that it's going to have something to do with quoting and which shell interprets which parts of the string.  Perhaps a "sh -x ./test.sh" would shed some light on exactly what it's trying to do.